# How to change panel property using jQuery in asp.net web form

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have web form  with a panel which has form elements in side it. and i have two radio button also based on the selection of radio button i want to change the DefaultButton property of panel1 control to another like "btnASWebPages" based on which radio button is selected.

How i can change this property using jQuery. I have tried few option but didn't seem to work.

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnASArchive">
    <div id="AdvancedSearchBox" class="AdvancedSearchBox">
        <asp:Label ID="lblAdvancedSearch" CssClass="lblAdvancedSearch" runat="server" Text="SEARCH"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAdvancedSearch" CssClass="txtAdvancedSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div id="AdvanceSearchChoice" class="AdvanceSearchChoice">
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rbSearchArchive" CssClass="rbSearchChoice" runat="server" Text="Articles Archive" GroupName="rdAdvanceSearchChoice" Checked="True" />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rbSearchPages" CssClass="rbSearchChoice" runat="server" Text="Web Pages" GroupName="rdAdvanceSearchChoice" />
    </div>
</panel>
```

I have posted only related code for this issue as form is quite big to put all the code. Just to add more based on radiobutton selection i hide and unhide two different forms so that user can search in related area, But i have a problem where my client wants to activate search on enter key. in order to achive this i have to activate the default form related to radio button selection. For example if one select Archive option then archive form will be visible and vice versa.

Comment: That's server-side code.  You need to inspect the client-side code that is rendered in the browser to see if there is anything you can change there.  It may not be possible, depending on if the property is used at client side.

Comment: I need to change this DefaultButton="btnASArchive" from client side not server side..

Comment: I know, but it's a server-side property.  I'm just running a test application myself to see if that property is exposed to the client.  If it's not then you can't do it with javascript.  Do the radio controls cause postback?

Comment: This is how panel is show up on client side div id="MainContent_Panel1" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'MainContent_btnASArchive')">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When rendered in the browser, this...

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlTest" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnTestButton"></asp:Panel>
```

become this....

```
<div id="ctl00_MainContent_pnlTest" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'ctl00_MainContent_btnTestButton')"></div>
```

You need to unbind the keypress event and create a new one.  I think you're going about this the wrong way and that it should be done on the server in postback events of the radio controls.

Comment: Thanks, It works on server side is much easy.. I check which radiobutton is check and accordingly execute the code. Thanks..